# How to join two string with a new line between them?

Tags: python, string

I have two strings like this:

```
str1 = "my fav fruit apple"
str2 = "my fav vegetable carrot"
```

I want to join the two strings to become :

```
"my fav fruit apple
my fav vegetable carrot"
```

i.e.: become one string with a new line between them. How to do that?

Answer (score 43):

You can use the concatenation operator, `+`:

```
str3 = str1 + '\n' + str2
```

Or you can use the `join` method on your delimiter, `'\n'`:

```
str3 = '\n'.join([str1, str2])
```

The latter approach works well when you have a bunch of strings in an array.

```
lines = ['A Story', 'by Me', '', 'An aardvark escaped from the zoo.', '', 'The End']
story = '\n'.join(lines)
print(story)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way:

```
new_string = str1 + "\n" + str2
```