# Generate a multiline string from an iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

ths is probably a dumb question... I'm working with some data that is generated, line by line, after an iteration and I'd like to store the result for further processing in a multiline string. As an example, let me show you this:

```
is_string = """"""""
for i in range(1, 101):
    is_string += str(i)
print(is_string)
```

The result is: `123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100`

But I'd like it to be a multiline string:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
99
100
```

What is te correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083445/how-to-join-two-string-with-a-new-line-between-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `is_string  += str(i)` use this `is_string += str(i) + '\n'` instead

Answer (score 4):

You could build a multi line string as follows:

```
multi_line = '\n'.join(map(str, range(1, 101)))
print(multi_line)
```

Or iteratively as:

```
multi_line = '\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101))
```

These methods avoid string concatenation which should be avoided if possible as they are less efficient.

Strings have a [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) method which takes a list of strings to join together, so:

```
'\n'.join(['1', '2', '3'])
```

would give you a string:

```
1\n2\n3
```

(where `\n` is the newline character)

Answer (score 1):

```
is_string = """"""""
for i in range(1, 101):
    is_string += str(i) + "\n"
print(is_string)
```

Add a newline after each element.

Answer (score 1):

`is_string = is_string +  str(i) + '\n'`
Is this what your are looking for?
Be careful dealing with the '\n', you may use something like `is_string.split('\n')` to retreive each sub string

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to add `\n` character at the end of the each insertion and this will solve your problem:

```
is_string = """"""""
for i in range(1, 101):
    is_string += '{}\n'.format(str(i))
print(is_string)
```

hope, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a list

```
is_string = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    is_string.append(i)

for i in is_string:
    print(i)
```

or as a string adding a new line `\n` to each..

```
is_string = """"""""
for i in range(1, 101):
    is_string += str(i) + '\n'
    print(i)
```