# Python instructional code to print long strings with line breaks

Tags: python-3.x

What's wrong with this code?  Except for the print statement, it is the direct answer code from a Udacity learning python lesson.  It suggests `br` as an html response, but to me that didn't make sense in python.  The python run results print the letters `<BR>` between every letter of the string.

```
def breakify(strings):
    return "<br>".join(strings)

print(breakify("Haiku frogs in snow" "A limerick came from Nantucket" "Tetrametric drum-beats thrumming,"))
```

Output:

```
H<br>a<br>i<br>k<br>u<br> <br>f<br>r<br>o<br>g<br>s<br> <br>i<br>n<br> <br>s<br>n<br>o<br>w<br>A<br> <br>l<br>i<br>m<br>e<br>r<br>i<br>c<br>k<br> <br>c<br>a<br>m<br>e<br> <br>f<br>r<br>o<br>m<br> <br>N<br>a<br>n<br>t<br>u<br>c<br>k<br>e<br>t<br>T<br>e<br>t<br>r<br>a<br>m<br>e<br>t<br>r<br>i<br>c<br> <br>d<br>r<br>u<br>m<br>-<br>b<br>e<br>a<br>t<br>s<br> <br>t<br>h<br>r<br>u<br>m<br>m<br>i<br>n<br>g<br>,
```

Comment: Hint: What type is `'hello' 'world'`?

Comment: String, and thank you for fixing the formatting.

Comment: Make the string into a list and change "<br>" to "\n" if you want to see it on a console.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083445/how-to-join-two-string-with-a-new-line-between-them) helps.

Comment: Related: [String concatenation without '+' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18842779/4518341)

Comment: OK.  I understand the difference between "immutable" string and turning it into a list.  I'm working on the commands to then manipulate it.  Formatting is still a different issue, but I'll get back to it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The strings are being concatenated due to [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).

Simply put them in a list (or tuple) and separate them with commas.

Example with shorter strings for readability:

```
print(breakify(["Haiku", "limerick", "drum"]))
```

Output:

```
Haiku<br>limerick<br>drum
```

You got the output you did because [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes any iterable, and a string is an iterable. For example:

```
>>> '.'.join('hello')
'h.e.l.l.o'
```